# how to control state of checkbox of child view in ExpandableListview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In my `ExpandableListview`, I am using `Imageview` and `Checkbox` that resembles the shape image and name,

When I tick the `checkbox` of particular child item , the other child item also gets ticked , after scrolling the checked state changes ,

I needed multiple values to be selected.

Please help me to get this solved , I am in very need of this . Googled but not found working in my case

Thanks in advance.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


_childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);     

int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);

Log.e("childPosition", "karjeevch "+childPosition);

ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
switch (itemType) {

case 0:
    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
        viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
        viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);


        imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+_childText+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);
        viewHolder.shape_name.setText(_childText);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        final CheckBox shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;
        viewHolder.shape_name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (shape_name_temp.isChecked()==true) {
                    All_link.SHAPE=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });


        //new PerformBackgroungTask().execute();
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
    //break;



case 1:

    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_carat, null);
        viewHolder.carat_from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_carat_from);
        viewHolder.carat_to = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_carat_to);

        viewHolder.carat_from.setText("jdsv");
        viewHolder.carat_to.setText("jdsv");

        All_link.CARAT_FROM=viewHolder.carat_from.getText().toString();
        All_link.CARAT_TO=viewHolder.carat_to.getText().toString();

    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;


case 2: 

    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder(); 

        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_color, null);
        viewHolder.color_from = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spn_color_from);
        viewHolder.color_to = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spn_color_to);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SearchActivity.color_list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);               
        viewHolder.color_from.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewHolder.color_to.setAdapter(adapter);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        final Spinner color_from_temp=viewHolder.color_from;
        final Spinner color_to_temp=viewHolder.color_to;

        // Changing textcolor
        viewHolder.color_from.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    All_link.COLOR_FROM=color_from_temp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003974"));                         
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });
        viewHolder.color_to.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                All_link.COLOR_TO=color_to_temp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003974"));                         
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });  
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
```

Comment: again :) can you send the whole class with examples..i will run here..and find the issue for you :) If possible you can send me the whole project..it will be more helpful to find

Answer (score 1):

List view, recycler view follows **Lazy loading** concept and reuses the views you have created. Imagine it like a screen can hold  view at max and list has 1000 items, android uses the same 10 view for the 1000 items. You have to update the new item depending on the value of the new item and you have to do it for every new item else it will use the previous view with checked state of checkbox. I have explained it theoretically hope it helps. 
Tell me in case you want a practical implementation.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Let's look at the first line:

`_childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);`

When you call `getChild()` you are getting the model for your item view.  So if your item view has a check box, your model should have some sort of boolean property in it.  Do you understand?  There is a one-to-one match-up between your view and your model.

So instead of a string for example let's say your item model is class `Shape` and it has a boolean property called `marked`.  And let's have the text property `name`. So I should see in your code something like this:

```
final Shape item = (shape) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
...
viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
...
viewHolder.shape_name.setText(item.getName());
viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(item.isMarked());   //update view from model
viewHolder.shape_name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       ...
       item.setMarked(isChecked);   // update model from view
       }
    }
});
```

Now, If the value of your string alone can tell you whether the item should be checked or not, then maybe you don't need the boolean property.

---

> after scrolling the checked state changes

I don't see `shape_name.setChecked()` anywhere in your `getChildView()` method, so I can tell you what is happening.

Remember that ListView (and ExpandableListView) recycle their views, so that if you check a checkbox, then scroll it out of view, when you scroll it back into view, your `getChildView()` gets called again, which sets up the view *with the checkbox unchecked*.

When a user checks the checkbox, you must update the model in your ListAdapter in your `onCheckedChanged()` so that when the view is recreated, you can call `shape_name.setChecked()` and set the proper state of the checkbox.  ListView does not have any inherent state; your ListAdapter model is the only state the ListView has.

Also, you are only setting up your list item when `convertView` is null.  `convertView` is the recycled list item view.  If it is null, then there is no recycling, so you must inflate your list item view and create your ViewHolder.  If it is not null, then all you need to do is get the ViewHolder.  But in either case, you must do your setText(), setChecked(), load image, etc. so that if a view was recycled you clear out the old state of the view.

Comment: I repeated my code inside if (convertView==null)  in to else without inflating the layout also used setchecked true and false on statechanged ..but still same result

Comment: Please update the code in your question with the entire ListAdapter class you are using.